# How to call onkeypress event in a html page (Delphi)

Tags: html, delphi, events, browser, onkeypress

How can i call onkeypress event of a textarea control in a html page using WebBrowser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a way with late binding:

```
procedure TBrowserPageIE.Test;
var
  doc : OleVariant;
  el  : OleVariant;
  v   : OleVariant;
begin
  if FBrowser.Document <> nil then begin
    doc := FBrowser.Document;
    el := doc.getElementById('myTextArea');
    el.FireEvent('onkeypress', v);
  end;
end;
```

Please add some code for nil/exception handling.